# Design library api vis-a-vis scala Set's invariance

Tags: scala

Imagine an api for removing vertices and edges from a graph. I hope this api below is self-explanatory, but note `Addable` is a trait.

```
  /*
   * Convenience method for bulk removal of both vertices and edges
   */
  def -= (inputs: Set[Addable]): AbstractGraph[VertexID, Vertex, Edge] = {
    inputs foreach {
      case v : AbstractVertex[VertexID]  => -= (v.asInstanceOf[Vertex])
      case e : AbstractEdge[VertexID]    => -= (e.asInstanceOf[Edge])
    }
  }
```

This api function cannot be used for sets of concrete `Addable` (those extendending `Addable`) because of the invariance of `Set`. Any good ideas for working around it in the api, not at call sites?

Comment: Since the only method you invoke on `inputs` is `foreach`, `Set` seems like an odd choice anyway. Why not `Iterable`?

Comment: Great advice! I had totally missed that. Iterable is covariant indeed! and callers that pass in a `Set` get their set parameter implicitly converted to `Iterator`, so the api also affords some caller flexibility like that.

Comment: Note `_ match` may be omitted for conciseness.

Comment: `def -= (inputs: Set[_ <: Addable])` should work

Comment: Thanks! will try that next time around